# What is $ P(X_1+X_2+X_3 > 5)$ if $X_i$'s are i.i.d with given pmf?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1, X_2, X_3$ be i.i.d. discrete random variables with the probability mass function $p(k) = \dfrac{2}{3}^{k-1}\left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right) \forall k \ge 1$. Let $Y = X_1 + X_2 + X_3$. Then what is $\mathbb P(Y > 5)$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried using mgf..and i was able to calculate mgf and pgf as well ..but don't know how to proceed now

Comment: Please format the question with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It is unclear without proper formatting what $p(k)$ is. Feel free to correct my edit with what it should be.

Comment: @user741002 For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thanks @an4s for formatting the question..you have correctly formatted it...as i am new to this platform I didn't knew about mathjax

Comment: Your title should reflect the actual question. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question.

Answer (score 1):

One possible way is to calculate the probability directly: $\mathbb P(Y>5)=1-\mathbb P(Y\leq 5)$. Since $Y\geq 3$, there is only few possibilities for $Y$ to be less or equal $5$: $Y=3,4,5$. The events $\{Y=3\}$, $\{Y=4\}$, $\{Y=5\}$ are mutually exclusive and the probability of $\{Y\leq 5\}$ is the sum of probabilities of these events. Calculate one of probabilities for example:
$$
\mathbb P(Y=4)=\mathbb P(X_1+X_2+X_3=4) 
$$
$$= \mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=1, X_3=2)+\mathbb P(X_1=1, X_2=2, X_3=1)+\mathbb P(X_1=2, X_2=1, X_3=1) 
$$
$$= 3p(1)^2p(2)= 3\cdot \left(\frac13\right)^2\left(\frac23\cdot\frac13\right)=\ldots
$$

Comment: Thanks for answering this..this methods seems very time consuming..is there any standard approach for dealing with questions where sum of r.v is involved as in this case

Comment: Since we are dealing with a discrete distribution, no method can do without calculating and adding these three probabilities. You can get these probabilities from mgf or pgf and then sum up.

Comment: And how to get probabilities from mgf?

Comment: Can you find probabilities from pgf? If yes, you can transform mgf to pgf.

Comment: Look also at this example https://www.math.ucla.edu/~akrieger/teaching/18w/170e/invert-mgf.html

Comment: @NCh $Y$ can take values of $0,1,2$ too.

Comment: @Math-fun No. $X_1$ can take values $k\geq 1$, so $Y\geq 3$.

Comment: @NCh you are right: sorry!